# Database design - storing a sequence

Tags: database, sqlite, sequence

Imagine the following: there is a "recipe" table and a "recipe-step" table. The idea is to allow different *recipe-steps* to be reused in different *recipes*. The problem I'm having relates to the fact that in the *recipe* context, the order in which the *recipe-steps* show up is important, even if it does not follow the *recipe-step* table primary-key order, because this order will be set by the user.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
recipe-step table:

id | stepName | stepDescription
-------------------------------
1  | step1    | description1
2  | step2    | description2
3  | step3    | description3
...


recipe table:

recipeId | step
---------------
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
...
```

This way, the order in which the steps show up in the *step* column is the order I need to maintain.

My concerns with this approach are:

- if I have to add a new step between two existing steps, how do I query it? What if I just need to switch the order of two steps already in the sequence?
- how do I make sure the order maintains its consistency? If I just insert or update something in the *recipe* table, it will pop up at the end of the table, right?

Is there any other way you would think of doing this? I also thought of having a *previous-step* and a *next-step* column in the *recipe-step* table, but I think it would be more difficult to make the *recipe-steps* reusable that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, tables are *not* ordered.
Unless you are using an `ORDER BY` clause, database engines are allowed to return records in *any* order they feel is fastest (for example, a covering index might have the data in a different order, and sometimes even SQLite creates temporary covering indexes automatically).

If the steps have a specific order in a specific recipe, then you have to store this information in the database.

I'd suggest to add this to the `recipe` table:

```
recipeId | step | stepOrder
---------------------------
1        | 1    | 1
1        | 2    | 2
1        | 3    | 3
2        | 4    | 1
2        | 2    | 2
```

---

Note:
The `recipe` table stores the relationship between recipes and steps, so it should be called `recipe-step`.
The `recipe-step` table is *independent* of recipes, so it should be called `step`.
You probably need a table that stores recipe information that is independent of steps; *this* table should be called `recipe`.

Comment: But how do I tackle the scenario in which I need to add a new step between two already existing steps? This would mean I would have to change the step order for all of the next steps again? So I would actually update _all_ the steps related to a certain recipe even if I just need to add one. Isn't there any other simpler option? How do I even query something like that?

Comment: You would have to update all recipe steps, or just compute an order value between the other ones, like `1.5`.